# apex repeat with dynamic list

Tags: apex, community, list, repeat

i have a json string

```
 {
  "kind": "storage#objects",
  "items": [
    {
      "name" : "image.png",
      "id": "id_1",
      "mediaLink": "link",
      "contentType": "image/jpg"
    },
    {
      "name" : "image.png",
      "id": "id_1",
      "mediaLink": "link",
      "contentType": "image/jpg"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have a class in apex

```
public class JsonGCloudApiApex {
public class Item{
    public string name;
    public string id;
    public string mediaLink;
    public string contentType;  
}

public List<Item> items;

public static JsonGCloudApiApex parse(String json) {
    return (JsonGCloudApiApex) System.JSON.deserialize(json, JsonGCloudApiApex.class);
}}
```

i have in controller class

```
public List<JsonGCloudApiApex.Item> listItems {get; private set;}
...
objItems = parse(resp.getBody());
listItems = objItems.items;
```

This work very good, and i can see on logs the values are setting from model class.
I need to create a apex:repeat for list variable: listItems (from controller variable name )

I try to use

```
<apex:repeat value="{!listItems}" var="item">
        <tr>
            <td class="withborder" style="width: 40%;">{!item.contentType}</td>
        </tr>
    </apex:repeat>
```

But i get the error message: Unknown property 'JsonGCloudApiApex.Item.contentType', on the model class the variable name (contentType) is declared and public
How to create a list view on with apex:repeat to print key's values from list on controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide getters and setters to expose these properties to Visualforce:

```
public class JsonGCloudApiApex {
public class Item{
    public string name {get; set;}
    public string id {get; set;}
    public string mediaLink {get; set;}
    public string contentType  {get; set;}  
}
```

Comment: LOL i can't see on model class... thanks u David